# Are Lady slipper orchids self fertile, and how can you pollinate them?

Tags: orchids, pollination

I am trying to get seeds from a certain orchid ([Lady slipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypripedioideae)) I have.  Are they self fertile? What would be the best way to pollinate them?
The genus is Cypripedium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most Cypripedium are self-fertile, but pollination is tricky and requires special equipment. Germinating and growing is also a long and slow process. Probably starting new plants from divisions or buying new ones would be more satisfactory.

Comment: Thank you, the success of the process is what satisfy me :-) Any way, after some of my flowers fell, I see the fruit is staying (2 out of 10) does it mean it was pollinated, or just a chance?

Comment: If the fruit is staying, then there was pollination.